# hashing and salt not comparing correctly

Tags: php, hash, mcrypt

I have successfully gotten the salted hash saved into the database.  Now the problem i'm facing is exactly how to set it up to compare between them to login in.  Do i have to make the hash again?  and if i do make it again won't it be different? Right now the check says it works but i cannot sign with the password before it was hashed.
 the code below is what ive tried so far:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_DATABASE);
if(!$con){
echo "Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
//echo "Database connection Success...";
}

 $user_name =mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["login_name"]);  
 $user_pass =mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["login_pass"]);  
$cost = 10;
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+',  '.');
$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;


 $sql_query = "select  user_name,user_pass from user_info where  
user_pass ='$user_pass' and user_name = '$user_name'";  


$hash = crypt($user_pass, $salt);
if(crypt($user_pass,$hash)==$hash){
echo "works"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
 {  
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
 $name = $row["name"];  
 echo "Login Success..Welcome " .$name;
 }  
 else  
 {   
 echo "Login Failed.......Try Again..";  

}
}
```

Comment: You need to consider using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead. Random salts and stored in the same string as the hash

Comment: Also, [mcrypt is a dead project](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt) if you need another reason to switch

Comment: @Machavity It is deprecated in 7.1 and slotted for removal: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login will always fail because this query...

```
"select  user_name,user_pass from user_info where  
user_pass ='$user_pass' and user_name = '$user_name'"
```

... compares the user's entered password to the hashed stored password.

The better approach is:

1. `SELECT` record with the login username (ignoring password)
2. If no record is found, the username doesn't exist. Fail
3. Compare the password in that record with the password that was submitted.
4. If they don't match, the password is wrong. Fail.
5. Login successful.

You're making your life really difficult by trying to implement your own hashing when PHP provides this natively.  To hash password at account registration (suppose user chose `$clear_pwd`):

```
$hash_pwd = password_hash($clear_pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This generates a cryptographically secure salt and hash for you. `$hash_pwd` gets stored in the DB.  Now at login, on step 3 above (password verification), do:

```
if (password_verify($clear_pwd, $hash_pwd)){ 
    // $clear_pwd is correct
}else{
    // password is incorrect.
}
```

Simple!

Comment: if i add password_hash nothing gets inserted into the database. if i do it the other way (orignal way) then it works

Comment: ok so i can use password_hash because the php plugin im using isnt 5.5 or because the web host isnt 5.5. one of the two.

Comment: @blahblah sorry to hear that. If you have control over this, you should consider updating your PHP.  Even PHP 5.5 is already past its end-of-life support window, so older versions are definitely problematic. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history)